# error when i want take value core data in iOS

Tags: ios, search, copywithzone

when i want to search core data in map view aim unable to search the data please help me iam getting this error as

```
2014-02-21 09:43:31.268 naveen[674:a0b] -[Search copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a48100
2014-02-21 09:43:31.273 naveen[674:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Search copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9a48100'
```

when want to print that string aim getting output as

```
<Search: 0x9a48100> (entity: Search; id: 0x9a2d070 <x-coredata://2A0FA356-68F2-43DE-A8DE-DCE8DE44145A/Search/p1> ; data: {
    text = pub;
})
```

Comment: Please attach the code. From this log I see that you try to call `copyWithZone` on `Search` class. `Search` doesn't implement this method.

Comment: UIStoryboard*thestory=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
//    
    ResultView *scord=(ResultView*)[thestory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"search"];
//    
//  
    special1=[self.personFRC objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//  ;
    NSLog(@"%@",special1);
        scord.string=special1;
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:scord animated:YES];

Comment: from hear to when i want to pass data to    hear MKLocalSearchRequest *request = [[MKLocalSearchRequest alloc] init];
    request.naturalLanguageQuery = _string;
    MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01);
    request.region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation.location.coordinate, span);
    MKLocalSearch *search = [[MKLocalSearch alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D loc = [userLocation coordinate];
iam getting that error